# What part in cppreference tells me structured binding declarations only work with compile-time known objects?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, structured-bindings

### My question is

What part of the cppreference.com's page on [structured binding declarations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) should make apparent that they cannot be used with "things" not known at compile time?

That page does not contain any explicit reference to compile or run time.

### Why?

I recently bumped into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077383/does-structured-binding-work-with-stdvector) about whether structured binding declarations work with `std::vector`, which doesn't since its size is not known at compile time. Since I'm trying to understand how [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) works, I need to make clear in my mind what the detailed distinction between run time and compile time is, hence I took the chance to ask the question above.

Comment: The "compile-time" was a bit of simplification. `std::array` goes into Case 2, `std::vector` would go into Case 3, but it doesn't have any public members to bind.

Comment: Of interest: [Runtime vs. Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846103/6865932)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, since _Case 1: if E is an array type, then the names are bound to the array elements_, but you say `std::array` goes into Case 2, I guess I'm a bit confused. Maybe you can help further?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis "array type" = C-style array. `std::tuple_size` has [a specialization for `std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_size), so it goes to the second case.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, I feel stupid now for not thinking about the C-style array. Thanks, and also thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant part is `std::tuple_size`, which yields a compile-time size. You can't implement that for `std::vector`. It has a run-time variable `std::vector::size`.