Is it safe to reinterpret the std::vector::data() member as a pointer to a C array?
I'm trying to use a structured binding like
std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
auto [a, b, c] = *(int(*)[3])v.data();

I don't know if the cast to a pointer-to-array is safe.
C++ reference does show a similar example but not exactly this example.
Their example
int b[6][3][8];
int (*p2)[3][8] = b; // pointer to the first element b[0] of the array b,
                     // which is an array of 3 arrays of 8 ints


The example you are referring to has nothing to do with this. The implicit conversion from array to pointer is not a cast of any kind.

Sort-of related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077383/does-structured-binding-work-with-stdvector

auto [a, b, c] = *(int(*)[3])v.data();, for this capture you do NOT need to use a cast at all. Look at what .data() returns it is allready a pointer and you can use that pointer from "C" directly. (Just don't let the "C" code call free on it)

@PepijnKramer the question has nothing to do with C. And you can't initialize a structured binding from a raw pointer. Hence the cast and dereference.

@RemyLebeau The title seemed to suggest differently, but you're right :)

Why not just write 3 lines of code?
